# Flutter: Are we forced to use null safety on master branch?

Tags: flutter

I upgraded a project to latest master and it's lit up like a xmas tree with 144 errors because null-safety seems to be enabled by default.

I'm working on a desktop app, and need Master, but am not ready to migrate to null safety yet. Is it possible to turn this off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we are not forced. [Null safety is available in the Flutter beta channel](https://flutter.dev/docs/null-safety). Some packages are fully null safety though. You can [unsound null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety)  as well.

Comment: Thanks! `dart --no-sound-null-safety run` seems to be what I would be after if I wanted to migrate more smoothly.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the language version in the entrypoint, which might be `lib/main.dart` as a comment on the first line

```
// @dart=2.11
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Null safety starts in 2.12, so using the version below that should avoid it.